# Form Submit Not working on IE intermittently with Spring MVC in backend

Tags: submit

I have a simple form on jsp file :

```
<form:form method="POST" class="my-form" id="dummyExtDelSubmitForm" name="dummyExtDELSubmitForm"   action="/my-web/landingPage/showPage">               
 <input type="text" name="viewName" value="userRegistrationPage" >              
 <input type="submit" name="submitDummYForm" value="Submit" ></input>               
</form:form>
```

on Spring MVC Controller I have the below method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView redirectToPage(@ModelAttribute("baseUserVO") BaseUserVO baseUserVO, HttpServletRequest request,Model model) throws BrownApplicationException {

 HttpSession session = request.getSession();

 if (baseUserVO != null && baseUserVO.getViewName()!=null) {
       return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + viewName, CommonConstants.MODEL, model);
     else{
       return new ModelAndView("redirect:/landingPage/home.brd", CommonConstants.MODEL, model);
 }
}
```

Problem is when I submit the form , the BaseUserVO object is populated sometimes and most of the time it is not. it works fine on Firefox without fail.
I tried to see the request in fiddler , in the form submit request to showPage , i don't see the parameters going , as per the logic if the viewName is not present, then redierect to landingPage/home , in the later redirection I do see the viewName parameter.

Code for BaseUserVO which is just a POJO :

```
public class BaseUserVO {
    private Integer userMasterId;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Integer relationshipCode;
    private String relationshipName;
    private String userName;
    private String userDisplayName;
    private String viewName;
    private String wpoId;
    private String userType;

    public Integer getUserMasterId() {
        return userMasterId;
    }
... getter seetter for other attributes.
```

Not sure whether it's a problem from Server side or client, Please reply if any clue.

Thanks,
Lalit

Comment: Just to add the problem occurs only on IE on HTTP based Tomcat  with SSL enabled the problem doesnt arise, if anybody has any clue kindly let me know , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue , its and IE with automatic authentication issue (see below Link), although no concrete solution so far but there are some workarounds.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Comment: How did you change your code in order to make it work? I got the exact same issue with Spring 4.0.6 on JBoss 7.2. I'm using Kerberos authentication (Spring Security JEE pre-authentication). Looking forward for your answer. Thank you.